# CoffeeScript: how to slice a string and get only the last 2 characters

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm getting started with CoffeeScript and I got stucked, but couldn't figure out how to trim and get the last characters of a string. How can I convert this into coffee?

```
if (m.length > 2) {
    m = m.slice(-2);
}
```

Comment: If you remove the parentheses, the braces and the semicolon, you got valid CoffeeScript.

Comment: This way? `if m.length > 2 then m = m.slice(-2)`

Comment: It compiled correctly, but did not work as I intended. Probably there's an error elsewhere. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
if m.length > 2
  m = m.slice(-2)
```

This is the code. 
You can convert any of your existing javascript code to coffee script using the free tool http://js2.coffee/

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
string.slice( beginslice [, endSlice] )
```

So,  for your example, try `m.slice -2`.